# I'm having trouble making the parent div expand to fit its content

Tags: html, css, overflow, expand, contain

I want the header `div` (containing the `background` and greeting text) to stretch to accomodate the text when the window is resized (expand along with its content). I tried adding `overflow:auto` and `overflow:hidden` to the header `div` as well as its parent container, but with no luck. 
Are there conflicts in my code that are causing this not to work?

Here's a jsfiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/gxpwxhfh/

I have this html for the header portion:

```
<div class='wrap'>   
<div id='header'>
    <div id='about'>

        <div id='hello'>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </div>

        <p id='message'>Lorem ipsum dolor<br />sit amet, consectetur<br />adipiscing elit.
        </p>

        <div class='button'>
            <a class='btn' href='#portfolio'>Lorem!</a>
            <a class='btn' href='#contact'>Ipsum!</a>
        </div>   
    </div>     
</div>
</div>
```

Styled by this css:

```
.wrap {
display: block;
float: left;
min-width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}

#header {
display: block;
float: left;
background: #fff;
min-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
min-height: 100vh;
background-image:url(http://i.imgsafe.org/81ed908.jpg);
overflow: auto;
}

#header, #footer {width: 100%;}

#about {    
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
top: 24%;
left: 25%;
width: 48%;
text-align: center;
font: 300 3.3em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
}

#hello {
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 700;
}

.button {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px 0px;
}

.btn {
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 46px;
margin-right: 6px;
margin-left: 6px;
padding: 9px 27px 9px 27px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
color: #fff;
background: #2de0bc;
-webkit-border-radius: 5;
-moz-border-radius: 5;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
background: #56edcc;
text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:visited {color: #fff;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some media queries in css

```
@media(max-width:960px){
  #about{
    font-size: 2.5em;
  }
}
@media(max-width:767px){
  #about{
    position: static;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gxpwxhfh/7/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` from `#about`

Comment: Right, so should I just use margins to position the element then and not absolute positioning?

Comment: If you use absolute positioning element is "removed" from flow of elements. It means it can't be affected by any other element.  As long as you can you should use default static position and position elements using margins, paddings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br />` tag from greeting text.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxpwxhfh/4/)